# var and let strange behavior

Tags: javascript, scope

in the following code if I use 'var' it outputs "undefined" and if I use 'let' it will produce and error "x is not defined"

```
function foo() {


    function bar() {
       console.log(x);
    }

    bar();

    var x = 14;

}

foo();
```

can some one explain it why

Comment: And some good read about *hoisting in Javascript* would help

Comment: Short answer without digging into the language spec is *never use variables before they're declared*. Then you don't have to worry about the differences.